# The Shift key fires the KeyDown event but does not fire the KeyUp event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a simple form without any controls.
I defined the KeyDown, KeyPress and the KeyUp events at form level.
The KeyPreview property is set to true. The code is as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);
        this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyPress);
        this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyUp);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("KeyDown.");
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("KeyPress.");
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("KeyUp.");
    }
}
```

The question is: how can I force the KeyUp event to fire, as the KeyDown event fires consistently every time I press the Shift Key but no KeyUp is fired?
Alternatively, is there any reliable way to detect the Shift key release, by another method, not using the KeyUp event?

Comment: Steve, I commented out the MessageBoxes in all three event handlers and I placed BreakPoints in each in stead.  I do not get any KeyUp event, as the BreakPoint in the KeyUp event handler is never reached when I press the Shift key. Only the BreakPoint in the KeyDown event handler is reached.

Comment: KeyPreview is intended for VB6 compatibility, it was necessary in that language to implement shortcut keystrokes.  If your form has any controls then your form's KeyDown event will still fire, even though it does not have the focus.  But not KeyUp.  We cannot tell from your snippet why you need that event.

Comment: Did you press just the Shift key or did you press it together with another key? I have placed some Console.WriteLine to see the output and it works (no message box and no breakpoints, not sure but I suspect that they mess with the keyboard buffer)

Comment: Steve, I only press the Shift key.

Comment: Hans Passant, I presented here only a simplified snippet. My program has to detect pressed keys. It works well for most of the keys and combinations of modifier keys and a nonmodifier key. It does however not work for the Shift key. The KeyDown event handler is always activated when I press the Shift key, but the KeyUp event is not. I need the KeyUp event in order to know that all the pressed keys have been released. I only display the pressed key(s) when all have been released.

Comment: Hans Passant, I am sorry. I did not even notice that the answer is in your comment:  KeyDown event will still fire... But not KeyUp, because of KeyPreview.  Hans Passant